# Fatal error después de haber metido algo que no era una etiqueta html en el editor

Tags: php

Advertencia : require_once(/home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php): No se pudo abrir la secuencia: No existe tal archivo o directorio en /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-settings.php en la línea 154

Error fatal : no detectado Error: Error al abrir requerido '/home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/share/pear') en /home/qbtyqepd /public_html/wp-settings.php:154 Rastreo de pila: #0 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-config.php(87): require_once() #1 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-load.php(50 ): require_once('/home/qbtyqepd/...') #2 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/qbtyqepd/...') #3 {main} lanzado en /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-settings.php en la línea 154

Advertencia : require_once(/home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php): No se pudo abrir la transmisión: No existe tal archivo o directorio en /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/load.php en la línea 1365

Error fatal: Error no detectado: Error al abrir requerido '/home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/share/pear') en /home /qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/load.php:1365 Rastreo de pila: #0 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(174): wp_load_translations_early() #1 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(154): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false) #2 /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/wp-includes/class- wp-fatal-error-handler.php(58): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #3 [función interna]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} lanzado en /home/qbtyqepd/public_html/ wp -incluye/cargar.php en la línea 1365

Alguien sabría cómo solucionar esto? He probado varrias cosas y no ha servido ninguna:'3